# Authorize a Google Drive Service java with Client Login?

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, google-drive-api

With the DocumentsList API, there was the possibility to authorize a DocsService, and so make authorized request with the Client Login method, i.e. service.setUserCredential(username,password).

Now that both DocumentsList and ClientLogin have been deprecated, is there a similar way to authorize a Drive service, without using tokens and authorization requests? Otherwise, if my application does not need to access logged user's data, but just a specific account's data (i.e. account of the application itself), what is the best way to authorize the Drive service to that specific account?

Answer (score 1):

The only supported way to authorize Drive API requests is OAuth 2.0 as username and password should never be required by a third-party app.

If you want to use the application's storage, you can authorize your app using service accounts: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: I had already read the ServiceAccount docs, and i found that probably the AppEngineIdentity service could solve my problem (I'm using GAE), but unfortunately I need to access the 'application' account as a real and normal account, that is I need to have a list of files in Drive etc., while the account that GAE provides for the applications seems to be just a service to make authenticated requests.